# How to destroy GameObject with Oculus Touch GazeRing?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I integrated Oculus VR in a simple scene which consists basically of only a sphere:

Now I want to "destroy" the sphere when point-selecting it with the right-hand Oculus Touch device. The Blue GazeRing hangs under the RightHandAnchor.

[See screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAcYR.png)

The Sphere, called and tagged Ball, is configured as follows:
[Configuration of the sphere game object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jAG7.png)

The InputManager GameObject has a component "Controller Input (Script)":

```
public class ControllerInput : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform pointerTransform;
 void Update () {
 if (OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.SecondaryHandTrigger))
 {
     RaycastPointer();
 }
}
private void RaycastPointer()
 {
     RaycastHit selection;
     if (Physics.Raycast(pointerTransform.position,pointerTransform.forward, 
     out selection)) 
          {
             if (selection.collider.gameObject.CompareTag ("Ball")) 
             {    
             Destroy(selection.collider.gameObject);
             }
         }
    }
 }
```

As variable pointerTransform, the GazeRing is given.

However, if I try to "shoot" the sphere with the trigger button. Nothing happens.

Can anyone advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your code runing the `RaycastPointer` function? If so have you tried to draw a ray with the Raycast specs to check where the controller is poiting at? Seems you need to debug your code

Comment: Thanks @Chopi, that was already a good hint!
It turns out that my method RaycastPointer() is not called at all because the update method does not recogonize the if (OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.SecondaryHandTrigger)) boolean, even if I hit the SecondaryIndexTrigger, but I don't know why yet.

Comment: Update: strangely, it works when replacing Button.SecondaryIndexTrigger with Button.One ...

Comment: I have no idea about Oculus SDK... are you sure that the button you were pressing was the secondaryindextrigger?? https://docs.unity3d.com/es/550/Manual/OculusControllers.html

Comment: yes:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OculusControllers.html